# Accessing a file opened in the main class in other classes

Tags: java, class

This is a simple question with probably a simple answer but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere else.

I have an input file that I open up and do various things with using RandomAccessFile in one class.  I would like to pass that file onto another class so it can do various things with it as well.  I'm not sure how this would be done however.

Comment: Simple. Have one class have it as in instance (or static, depending on your case) variable, and pass it as a parameter to the other method in the other class.

Comment: How does a method take a file as a parameter in Java?

Comment: @Downvoter This is a good question and should be preserved for future reference (say, by intro Java students).

Answer (score 1):

Use a setter and pass the instance of the `RandomAccessFile` to the second class instance

```
myClassInstance.setFile(RandomAccessFile myFile);
```

Comment: @Downvoter This makes perfect sense (in fact, it is a good idea to have two references in two different classes referring to the same object).

Comment: @GasperGulotta you can't be downvoter yet because you need 125 rep atleast to downvote

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use [Singleton](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html) design pattern. Then you could access file across many places with `Singleton.getInstance().write("smth");`

Comment: why downvote? I think it is good idea to design object accessing I/O file as a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Make the file a parameter to a method or constructor of the other class. For example

```
public void displayFirstLine (RandomAccessFile myFile) {
    //your code here
}
```